# How do I look for a word in a string of randomly generated letters i C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that contiues to randomly generate a string of letters, but stop when it has generated a word the user have entered.

I have made it generate the letters but I don't know how to make it recognize a word from it.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {

    int n = rand() % 26;
    char c = (char)(n + 65);
    cout << c;

}
return 0;
```

I'm gonna change the for loop to a while loop when I know how to make it find the users input.

I'm very new to programming so the solution is most likely obvious.

Comment: I hope that by "stop when the word is generated" you mean that it will stop after every letter in the word is generated.  Otherwise you won't have much success

Comment: This is a tricky one because "very new to programming" can mean many things.  Are you familiar with `std::string`?  It would be part of the puzzle if you knew it.  Are you at a point where you are paying attention to performance (how fast the program runs)?  The trivial solutions have bad runtime performance, which likely won't matter here but could matter for future programs you write (don't want to get bad habits!)

Comment: If letters continue to be generated, eventually a real word will be generated and eventually one that matches the users input.

Comment: Eventually when?  How many letters in this word?  As the words get larger then it just won't happen sometimes.  The loop will run until it crashes.  That is if you are expecting the word to be "generated" in consecutive characters.  How often do you really think that is going to happen?

Comment: Prefer to use character literals instead of their decimal ASCII number, e.g.: 'A' instead of 65.

Comment: A more efficient algorithm may be to guess letter by letter.  For example, randomly guess the first letter, then the second, etc.  This should reduce the number of combinations.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to crack here, but that doesn't seem to be the way to approach it. Bear in mind the more characters this word you are looking for has, exponentially increases the unlikeliness of having it generated randomly to the point where you may run out of memory and never generate it.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments suggests, you need to create a string from your chars.  After that, I would suggest looking at:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

its a search function for strings used on other strings... which is exactly what you're looking for.

One of the comments also suggest using == to compare the string you created from chars and the user input string, but there isn't much use in doing it this way when the string::find function does the exact same thing but more efficently

Answer (score 0):

A Modern C++ solution.
The interesting part in the main function which is below.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>

void NotFoundMessage(std::list<char>& randomSequence); 
void FoundMessage(long long iterationCount);

// Seed with a real random value, if available
std::random_device r;
std::default_random_engine e1(r());    
// A random character between 'A' and 'Z'
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist('A', 'Z');

char nextRandomCharacter()
{
    return static_cast<char>(uniform_dist(e1));
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    // <--- NEEDS CHECKS IF INPUT IS CORRECT!!!!

    std::list< char > randomSequence;

    // Fill randomSequence with initial data
    for ( const auto& c : input )
    {
        randomSequence.push_back( nextRandomCharacter() );
    }

    long long iterationCount = 1;

    while ( !std::equal( input.begin(), input.end(), 
                         randomSequence.begin() ) )
    {
        NotFoundMessage( randomSequence );

        // remove character from front and add random char at end.
        randomSequence.pop_front();
        randomSequence.push_back( nextRandomCharacter() );

        iterationCount++;
    }

    FoundMessage(iterationCount);
}

void NotFoundMessage(std::list<char>& randomSequence)
{
    std::cout << "Not found in: ";
    for ( const auto& c : randomSequence )
        std::cout << c << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void FoundMessage(long long iterationCount)
{
    std::cout << "Found after " 
            << iterationCount 
            << " iterations." 
            << std::endl;
}
```